# boolean vs 2-item lists

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, frontend

I'm working on Front end using remote MYSQL for 1st time. Lots of boolean type data points.

Previously, I would use booleans and use code client-side to display a text value (0;Open, 1;Closed), etc.

Is it more standard to use a 2-row tables (such as below) to store/get these text values? I'd assume the additional JOIN(s) would be more overhead than converting the boolean to text at client side, particulary for just 2 items.
tb11

```
id value
01 open
02 close
```

what about a 6 item list table?

thanks!!

Comment: 6 items or 6 million -- Fine.  But it is no longer "Boolean"; Boolean has only to values.  Instead `INT` or `TINYINT` would work as a datatype.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need a table

With

```
id templateid
```

And a table template with 4 rows

```
id val1 val2
1    0    0
2    1    0
3    0    1
4    1    1
```

If you have more values you need a bigger template table for all variations

that wll save a lot of space